# Powershell installation script wrapper based on OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Thanks a lot for your time in advance of reading this (it is going to be a long question).

I'm a newbie with a little knowledge of Powershell. I have a situation in which I'm creating an installation wrapper script.

This script will be executed on many user machines, and they may/may not have Active directory access.

But the script should be in such a way that, if the Machine object is part of a specific OU in active directory, then it should choose the configuration file accordingly.

Will the OU information be stored somewhere in the WMI? What is ADSI searcher, will it need any special access or pre-requisites to work properly?

I have googled and got the below script using ADSI and it seems to be working on my virtual machine, but not on a few other virtual machines (for reasons unknown to me).

```
$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName

$ADSISearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher

$ADSISearcher.Filter = '(&(name=' + $ComputerName + ')(objectClass=computer))'

$ADSISearcher.SearchScope = 'Subtree'

$Computer = $ADSISearcher.FindAll()

$OU = $($Computer.Properties.Item('distinguishedName'))
```

I've tried running the script on various other user machines (mixed AD access levels), and `$OU = $($Computer.Properties.Item('distinguishedName'))` is giving error.

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>        At line:1 char:42
>        +         $OU = $($Computer.Properties.Item < <<< ('distinguishedName')) + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Item:String) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

But `$computer` is not a null value. It has the result below (I have modified the LDAP info..)

```
 Path                                                        Properties
----                                                        ----------
LDAP://CN=,OU=< ........>,OU=V< ...>,OU=N... {primarygroupid, iscriticalsystemobject, msds-supportede...
```

Now the question is: Am I in the right direction, will ADSI searcher query this information from locally cached information?

If yes, can you help me fix this issue? If I'm all wrong, please correct me. I've been sitting with this for days now and help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"if the Machine object is part of a specific OU in active directory then, choose the configuration file accordingly"* - I think a Group Policy would be a better fit. You can set a group policy on each OU that runs a different logon script.

Comment: yes.. but the configuration file is passed to a installer which is pretty huge. so my clients are lil reluctant to it.

Comment: That error is saying that `$Computer.Properties.Item` is `null`. It's not `null` for me when I try it. But you can access the same attribute with `$Computer.Properties["distinguishedName"]`... maybe that works?

Comment: Maybe better use `$ADSISearcher.FindOne()` or loop through the results returned by `$ADSISearcher.FindAll()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot for helping me today! I definitely learned lot of info. I did take a U turn and i was looking through another route(definitely a very slow Query compared to ADSI).
But is working on cross domain Scenarios.
Ref:[How do I use WMI to get the current OU of a computer and list all other computers in that OU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381454/how-do-i-use-wmi-to-get-the-current-ou-of-a-computer-and-list-all-other-computer)

```
$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName;
$Computer = Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\directory\ldap' -Query "Select DS_distinguishedName from DS_computer where DS_cn = '$ComputerName'";
$OU = $Computer.DS_distinguishedName.Substring($Computer.DS_distinguishedName.IndexOf('OU='));
```

And it did the magic and i got the desired out from all my test VM's

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance the machines you are testing on are not joined to the domain?

Regardless, while I do recommend you choose a different solution other than the path you are going down, does this code work any better for you? Also note that you mentioned that the DCs may or may not be reachable. If that's the case this query will fail from the local machine (and retrieving the group policy from sysvol would too).

```
$LDAPDN = ([adsisearcher]"(&(name=$env:computername)(objectClass=computer))").findall().path

If ($LDAPDN) {
    $OU = $LDAPDN.Replace("LDAP://CN=$env:computername,","")
}

Else {
    Write-Warning "Unable to find $env:computername in AD or the adsi search failed"
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your valuable time and code. and i did try your code, got the warning message you presented. But I'm sure the machine is in Vcenter and there would not be connection issue. But as you suggested, i'm starting to think for other possible solutions. Thanks again for your help here on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this if you run it with a user account that is not on the same domain as the computer. It tries to search the domain of the user and then doesn't find the computer. So you need to specifically tell it to connect to the domain of the computer, which you can find using:

```
$ComputerDomain = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain
```

There are also some short forms you can use, like `[adsi]` and `[adsisearcher]` to make the code more succinct.

The `DirectorySearcher` (aka `[adsisearcher]`) used here is .NET's [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=netframework-4.8), which is part of the .NET Framework and will be installed by default in Windows. So you don't need to worry about it not being available. But the computer does need to be connected to the network for this to work.

```
$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName
$ComputerDomain = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain

$ADSISearcher = [adsisearcher]"(&(name=$ComputerName)(objectClass=computer))"
$ADSISearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")
$ADSISearcher.SearchRoot = [adsi]"LDAP://$ComputerDomain"

$Computer = $ADSISearcher.FindOne()

$DN = $Computer.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]
$OU = $DN.Substring($DN.IndexOf("OU="))
```

Note that the [`SearchRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchroot?view=netframework-4.8) is set to the domain of the computer.

The [`SearchScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchscope?view=netframework-4.8) is `Subtree` by default, so you don't need to set that.

It's a good idea to use [`PropertiesToLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload?view=netframework-4.8) to tell it which attributes you want it to return. Otherwise, it will return every attribute with a value. It probably won't make much of a difference here, but it can in other cases.

I also used `FindOne()`, which returns a single value, instead of `FindAll()`, which returns an array. Really, there should only be one result anyway, which is why you can treat the array as if it wasn't.

Note that the `distinguishedName` attribute is the full path to the object, not just the OU. So if you want the OU, you need to extract that portion of the `distinguishedName`, which is what I did here. (all attributes are presented as arrays, which is why you need `[0]` there)

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me understand. I did try your script on one of the failed machines and unfortunate that i failed for the same reason

Comment: $DN = $Computer.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:49
+ $DN = $Computer.Properties["distinguishedName"][ <<<< 0]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: Yes this is the error. Find one is successfull.  and even $computer has search values.PS C:\Users\adoss> $computer

Path                                                        Properties
----                                                        ----------
LDAP://<Domain>/CN=<machine name>,OU=<OU>... {distinguishedname, adspath}